# Hide / Show Custom field depending of the page ID (Magic Field 2)

Tags: custom-field, plugin-magic-fields

I use Magic Field 2 to display custome field on my page !

However, I would like to be able to hide several field depending on the page ID...

I do not want to use custom post type because my website rely on basic page.

Any idea on how I could do that ? Using javascript perhaps ?

I can't figure out, which hook I should use.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Cheers,

Jk_

Comment: a single field within a meta box, or whole meta boxes?

Comment: A whole meta box if it's possible.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove meta boxes with the [`remove_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) function:

```
function wpse50430_remove_meta_boxes() {

    // make sure we're on an admin screen and `post` is set
    if( !is_admin() && !isset( $_GET['post'] ) )
        return;

    if( $_GET['post'] == 99 ): // editing page ID 99
        remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', 'page', 'normal' );
    endif;

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse50430_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

To remove meta boxes added by plugins, you have to find the handle ID. If you use Chrome's developer tools, you can right-click the meta box and look for the ID of the element with class `postbox`.

Comment: Hi Milo, it is weird because it doesn't work... I got no error, I double check the ID of the meta box. I even tried with an other meta box. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok it works if I replace admin_menu by admin_head !

Comment: @Jk_ `add_action` also has a priority parameter you can change, it's possible the meta boxes were being added after you're trying to remove them in `admin_menu`.